# Show all pages of a PDF using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox

I'm new in Apache PDFBox, I used org.apache.pdfbox.PDFReader to open PDF and etc,
but now I need to show in JFrame PDF documents all pages in one JPanel, is it possible?
[image: like this]

Comment: Your question is unclear, and I suspect it isn't related to PDFBox at all. PDFBox can return BufferedImages for each page. What do you want if e.g. the PDF has 1000 pages so that you have an array of 1000 images? Show all 1000 pages in one single panel at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described before I needed to show all pages of PDF document in a jframe, for it I have used org.apache.pdfbox.PDFReader as follow:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.pdfbox.PDFReader;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageWrapper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

public class CustomPDFReader extends PDFReader {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 678451510308887925L;

public CustomPDFReader() {
    super();
}

public void setCurrentFile(String file) {
    try {
        Method m = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("openPDFFile", 
                new Class<?>[]{String.class, String.class});
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(this, file, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String []args) {
    CustomPDFReader reader = new CustomPDFReader();
    // remove menubar
    JMenuBar menu = reader.getJMenuBar();
    menu.setVisible(false);

    JPanel header = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel firstLine = new JPanel();

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
    firstLine.add(label);

    JPanel secondLine = new JPanel();

    JTextField text = new JTextField();
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    secondLine.add(text);

    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    secondLine.add(button);

    header.add(firstLine, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
    header.add(secondLine, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    reader.getContentPane().add(header, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // set default opened file
    reader.setCurrentFile("test.pdf");
    reader.showAllPages();
    reader.setVisible(true);
}

private void showAllPages() {
    try {
        Field pages = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("pages");
        pages.setAccessible(true);
        List<PDPage> pagesList = (List<PDPage>) pages.get(this);

        Field documentPanel = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("documentPanel");
        documentPanel.setAccessible(true);
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) documentPanel.get(this);
        panel.remove(0);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 1);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        for(PDPage page : pagesList) {
            PageWrapper wrapper = new PageWrapper(this);
            wrapper.displayPage(page);
            panel.add(wrapper.getPanel());
        }
        pack();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

PDFBox version is 1.8.10. Sample project you can find [there](https://github.com/daniyar-artykov/demo-projects/tree/master/pdf-viewer)

Comment: please provide the version of your pdfBox because the code dont work for me !

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb I've edit my answer, pls take a look at the last line